# Error: openxlsx can only read .xlsx files while reading .xslm file in R

Tags: r, readxl, openxls

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)

source("global_config.R")


inputFile <- "../data/census.xlsm"
peopleData <-read.xlsx(inputFile, sheet = "peopleData", startRow = 16 )
view(peopleData)
```

I am getting the following error
**Error: openxlsx can only read .xlsx files**
openxls version 4.2.4
readxl version  1.3.1

Comment: Refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215381/does-the-xlsx-package-work-for-xlsm-files-in-r

Comment: Can't we use openxslx package for reading .xslm file @ADUBEY

Answer (score 0):

Try using the read.xlsx2() function, described in more detail here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf